# Redirect user to another page when he likes a page tab

Tags: php, facebook, api

I had this block of code working but not anymore...

Index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '453976824647366',
            'secret' => 'fe86f3b0b34b3ed6eXXXXXX',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$liked = $signedRequest["page"]["liked"];

        if ($liked) {
            header('Location:youlike.php');
        } else {
            echo "you don't like";
        }
?>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

youlike.php

```
You like!
```

It always displays "you don't like", seems it never goes into youlike.php

Some help would be appreciated once again!

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['signed_request'])) {
    list($sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_POST['signed_request'], 2);
    $decoded = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
    $liked = $decoded["page"]["liked"];
}

if ($liked) {
    header('Location:youlike.php');
    exit;
}
else {
      echo "you don't like";
}
?>
```

Comment: @arn - so the problem was that you didn't have the call to `exit()`?

Comment: I have just some problems to understand the meaning of the first lignes in the first "if". Maybe you could develop a bit for me ? thx

Comment: If you open a custom tab then Facebook makes a POST request to your app that has details about the user in encoded and signed (so you know it really is Facebook who is running your app in iFrame) format. You could use Facebook app to decode these (like you do in your own script) or if you don't care you can just decode manually and ignore the signature. More info about the signed request format can be found from Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in an iframe, you'll need to perform the redirect on the top most frame.

Try this JavaScript -

```
top.location.href = "youlike.php";
```

With php you could simply echo out the code like this -

```
echo '<script type="javascript">';
echo 'top.location.href = "'.$youlike.'";';
echo '</script>';
exit();
```

Depending on the complexity of your pre/post like pages, you might want to simply have all the content on one page and only display certain parts of it if the user "likes" the page.

```
if ($liked) {
  // place like post page HTML here
} else {
  // place like pre page HTML here
}
```

Comment: I tried the second code you have... this is not working for me actually :(

I just put it instead of header('Location:youlike.php');

Comment: @arn - are you getting any errors?  In the javascript or php?

Comment: can you see the javascript code on the page? is it in the right place?  You could try place an `alert()` there to see if the code is in fact being executed...

Comment: you can see what it gives here : http://www.facebook.com/Luthe131/app_453976824647366

Comment: I tried to re-use a if , else as in my first message but i always get " you don't like" , it never goes into youlike.php that contains "you like!"

Comment: this is unbelievable, it's now working : try to have a look 
http://www.facebook.com/Luthe131


locally, it didn't work a few minuts ago